# Remove db $conn from MYSQLI query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently learning mysqli and systematically replacing all of my deprecated queries throughout my script.

I have this query:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "name");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM pins WHERE id='$pinDetails->id'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
/* associative array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$feature = $row['featured'];
/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Which I can echo throughout the page as `<?php echo $row['date_featured']; ?>`

My question is how do I rework the code to remove the connection? I don't want to keep connecting to the db in every query when I have a general connection include at the top of the page.

Comment: I see only one connection here. If you remove that, there will be none and therefor no possibility to query data. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). And please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Comment: @GolezTrol, the page that this query is taken from contains a main connection to the database thus removing the need for individual connections within queries.

Comment: Okay, so do so. Instead of passing `$link` pass a reference to the connection made in your include. Do you want us to guess the name of the connection in the include? It might be named `$link` or `$connection`, or it might be stored in a singleton or static class, so something like `Database::getInstance()->getConnection()`. No way to tell. The connection, of course, must also be a mysqliconnection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need connection for this page to operate based on your SQL database ,, can you explain more that what do you mean by removing connection
you can use INCLUDE();

Comment: The connection, `$link` within this query. I want to remove it from the query so that it doesn't check for a connection before outputting data. The reason for this is because the page as a whole contains a database connection via a `<?php include ?>`.